# How do you use socket.io version 3 with Phaser version 3?

Tags: socket.io, phaser-framework

I've worked with several tutorials on writing multi-user games using Phaser 2 and socket.io version 2. They don't seem to work with version 3 of both products.

Can anyone point me to resources for learning how to use these two products together?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Here is a link to a [tutorial on Phaser 3 + Socket.io](https://gamedevacademy.org/create-a-basic-multiplayer-game-in-phaser-3-with-socket-io-part-1/).

Comment: @brae Thank you. This is exactly the tutorial that I've been working from. When you add the following code as recommended in the tutorial:

    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var server = require('http').Server(app);
    var io = require('socket.io').listen(server); 

the result is:

    listen is not a valid method. 

Several tutorials use this same coding. There is one tutorial that I've completed that does not use an authoritative server. In order for that tutorial's code to run, I had to install socket.io v 2.3.0 instead of v 3. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're initializing socket.io incorrectly. See here for more details on [how to initialize your socket.io server](https://socket.io/docs/v3/server-initialization/).

```js
const httpServer = require("http").createServer();
const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
  // ...
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  // ...
});

httpServer.listen(3000);
```